# Getting system check errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I am trying to set a local development environment for a very complex web application. There is no proper documentation for setting up the environment, so it's been two days I am resolving errors by myself. After resolving all the errors, I am getting system check errors mentioned below and I don't understand what they mean? Can somebody help, what these errors mean and how to resolve them.

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'credits.admin.creditshistoryAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[29]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'creditshistoryAdmin', or an attribute of 'credits.CreditsHistory'.

<class 'credits.admin.creditshistoryAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[30]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'creditshistoryAdmin', or an attribute of 'credits.CreditsHistory'.
```

Comment: show the admin code what u have tried so for

Answer (score 3):

The class `credits.admin.creditshistoryAdmin` has an attribute `readonly_fields`.

It's a list of fields that are shown as read-only in the admin (see docs on [`ModelAdmin.readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)).

Items of that list should either be callables, or attributes of the admin (`creditshistoryAdmin`) or the model (`credits.CreditsHistory`). But the items at the 30th and 31st position (so readonly_fields[29] and [30]) are something else.

For further diagnosis, you have to post the code of `credits.admin.creditshistoryAdmin` and `credits.models.CreditsHistory`.

Comment: Note that having at least 30 items in readonly_fields sounds like a serious usability issue in the first place.